# How to check file integrity before ftp

Tags: ftp, apache-commons, file-transfer

I'm using apache commons ftp client to transfer files. Although not very often I see some partial transfers. I am not sure if its because ftp has partial file during transfer because when I check after some time, I see file in normal size. 
Is there a way to understand file integrity before starting transfer? Is there an existing mechanism (searching eof, renaming file etc..) inside apache ftp client already for this? Already checkhed internet but found nothing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will certainly have tools for checking file integrity, but I don't know if they are provided with the FTP client. You may need to create scripts for the job. The question doesn't make it 100% clear at what stage the check needs to be done.

To add a layer of "checks and balances" to a file transfer, most people will commonly generate an MD5 checksum (or other checksum; MD5 is the most common but it's not considered the highest-performing) before the transfer, and then when the transfer is complete run an MD5 on the destination and compare the two. Identical files will yield identical checksums.

A custom protocol makes it possible to run checksums on the fly as well, but with pure FTP your best bet is to write pre- and post- transfer checksum scripts.

Does that answer the question? If not, a few more details might give me and others a better picture.

Comment: Thank you for response. Especially clues related how to achieve such a task helped me. I have tried a few new tests related partial file transfer and get more confused because somehow apache client doesnt allow partial file transfer and raise error when i try.However in a case i have seen that our application transfered a file which is not complete without an error.For now i will check transfered file size with local file and will add md5 chechksum soon.Thanks again.